# How to determine the source event caused the call bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post?

Tags: python, add-on

Blender will call this handler on every update of location change even if it happens via user moved the object or changed via property window. My issue is I cannot distinguish it.
Is there anyway to determine the source of the update? ie. Whether the event is happened on user dragged the object or through they changed location through property window?

If there is no way to distinguish it, how I can keep track of the location of objects I have created?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, iyou may want to explore the msgbus system